# "A Connection attempt Failed.." Error during at Soap Request in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, soap

I have connected a Third Party Web service with my web application, it is working fine
in **localhost** . But after i uploaded the project in server it is showing the following error.

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a   period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 100.100.100.100:9090
```

Here is my Soap Request:

```
  StringBuilder soapmsg = new StringBuilder();
    soapmsg.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
    soapmsg.Append("<soap:Envelope xmlns='http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05'   xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:wsse='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext'>");
    soapmsg.Append("<soap:Body><OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ EchoToken='' SequenceNmbr='0' TransactionIdentifier='0' Version='1.001' xmlns='http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05' DirectFlightsOnly='false'>");
    soapmsg.Append("<POS xmlns='http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05'><Source AgentSine='' PseudoCityCode='NPCK' TerminalID='1'><RequestorID ID='AFFILIATE'/></Source><YatraRequests><YatraRequest AffiliateID='YTFABTRAVEL' MidOfficeAgentID='' AgentEmailID='' Destination='' AgentTypeCode='' Description='' DoNotCache='false' DoNotHitCache='true' IsYatraAgent='' LastResultFromCache='true' RequestType='"+di+"' YatraRequestTypeCode='SMPA'/></YatraRequests></POS>");
    soapmsg.Append("<OriginDestinationInformation>");
    soapmsg.Append("<DepartureDateTime WindowAfter='" + flexi + "' WindowBefore='" + flexi + "'>" + date + "</DepartureDateTime>");
    soapmsg.Append("<OriginLocation CodeContext='IATA' LocationCode='" + origin + "'>'" + origin + "'</OriginLocation>");
    soapmsg.Append("<DestinationLocation CodeContext='IATA' LocationCode='" + destination + "'>'" + destination + "'</DestinationLocation>");
    soapmsg.Append("</OriginDestinationInformation>");
    soapmsg.Append("</OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(@"http://100.100.100.100:9090/services/spm/spm"));
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Accept = "text/xml";
    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", @"http://100.100.100.100:9090/services/spm/spm");
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    writer.Write(soapmsg);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();

    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05";
        XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
     }        


  **The following exception i got after i tried to connect the web service:**

    SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party     did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 100.100.100.100:9090]
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddresssocketAddress) +251System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4,  Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout,   Exception& exception) +279
```

I have searched a lot. I am new to web service.
 *Please let me know if you need more information.*
 Thanks in advance,

Comment: The Problem is solved simply.The Third Party did not provide rights to the Host Server. Now Working fine... :-)